# Google like edit/combo control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, combobox

Everyone probably knows what I mean, but to clarify the control would need to:

- Fire an event when user edits the text. The event would provide a SuggestionList: TStrings which you could fill with matches/suggestions.
- if the SuggestionList is not empty a drop down should appear.
- Unlike combo, the control should not attempt to automatically select/auto complete or otherwise affect the editing.

So, is there a Delphi edit/combo control that works like that ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [autocompletion feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292.aspx) built in to all Windows edit controls.

First, fill your `TStrings` object however you want. Then use [`GetOleStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AxCtrls.GetOleStrings) to create a [`TStringsAdapter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AxCtrls.TStringsAdapter) to wrap it. (The adapter does not claim ownership of the `TStrings` object, so you must make sure you don't destroy it while the adapter is still live.) The adapter gives you an `IStrings` interface, which you'll need because the autocompletion feature requires an [`IEnumString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687257.aspx) interface to provide the completion matches. Call [`_NewEnum`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AxCtrls.TStringsAdapter._NewEnum) for that.

Next, call [`CoCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615.aspx) to create an [`IAutoComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292.aspx) object. Call its [`Init`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776293.aspx) method to associate it with the window handle of your edit control. If you're using a combo box, then send it a [`cbem_GetEditControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775772.aspx) message to find the underlying edit window.

You can stop at that point and autocompletion should work automatically. You can disable autocompletion if you want, or you can set any number of [autocompletion options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762479.aspx).

You say you don't want autocompletion, but in the OS terminology, I think what you really don't want is called **auto append**, where the remainder of the string is entered into the edit box automatically as the user types, but selected so that further typing will overwrite it, and the user needs to delete the excess text if the desired value is shorter than one of the matches.

There is also **auto suggest**, which displays a drop-down list of suggestions.

You can enable either or both options. You don't need to filter the list of suggestions yourself; the autocomplete object filters the `IEnumString` list by itself.

Comment: This is nothing short of perfect, precisely what I want, I wasn't aware of autocompletion options, thanks.

Comment: IAutoComplete doesn't seem to support matching of any partial string, but only supports matching from the start. I mean, given two strings, 'bcd' and 'abcd', if I type 'bc', only 'bcd' will be matched, but I also want 'abcd' to be matched also.

Comment: Then "autocomplete" isn't the feature you wanted in the first place, @Edwin. It *completes* what you've already typed.

Comment: how it supports multiple entry? like outlook recipient edit box?

Comment: @Mohammad, the comments of an almost-four-year-old answer are not the place to ask a new question. Please use the "ask question" button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard `TComboBox` and faststrings library (for `stringMatches()` function).

```
procedure TForm1.cbChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  s:Integer;
  tmpstr:string;
begin
  //suggestions: tstringlist
  cb.AutoComplete:=false;
  tmpstr:=cb.Text;
  cb.Items.Clear;
  for s:=0 to suggestions.Count - 1 do
    if StringMatches(suggestions[s],cb.Text+'*') then
      cb.Items.Add(suggestions[s]);
  cb.DroppedDown:=(cb.Items.Count<>0) and (Length(cb.Text)<>0);
  cb.Text:=tmpstr;
  cb.SelStart:=Length(cb.Text)
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is close, but has few issues. When you enter first character in an empty combo, for a split second it will autocomplete it before you set the cb.text back to what it was.
Also if you move the focus to some other control while the dropdown is visible it will again autocomplete. And if you use the up/down keys to navigate the drop down items the text will again get autocompleted. And lastly you set the SelStart to the last character, but it should be set to where it was, so SelStart needs to be stored at the begging of the method and restored at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to show a file or url list:

```
SHAutoComplete(GetWindow(eb_MyComboBox->Handle, GW_CHILD), SHACF_AUTOSUGGEST_FORCE_ON | SHACF_FILESYS_DIRS);
```

Answer (score 2):

I first implemented this feature like Rob described it in his answer. Later I saw that `TComboBoxEx` has the property `AutoCompleteOptions` where I set `acoAutoSuggest` to `True` and `acoAutoAppend` to `False`. The ComboBox now filters its item list when doing some entry and shows the matching items.

I'm using RAD Studio 10 Seattle and XE2 but don't know if this feature is available in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

To the last bit of your question: "So, is there a Delphi edit/combo control that works like that ?":

A bit late to the party but yes, I have written a free and open source component that implements the Google Place Autocomplete and Google Place Details API's:

It does inherit from the standard TComboBox but you can modify the code to work with any TEdit

https://carbonsoft.co.za/components/

or

https://github.com/RynoCoetzee/TRCGPlaceAutoCompleteCombo

Answer (score 0):

This is an early version of a control I made.
It seems to work fine. But it might need improvements.

```
UNIT cvDropDownSearch;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GabrielM
  2023.10

  Searchbox with auto-suggest
  A dropdown box similar to the Help Insight in Delphi IDE.
  Displays a list of items. The list is filtered (gets smaller) as the user types in more characters into the searchbox.  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

//ToDo: Issue: the drop down does not respond to scroll
//ToDo: Issue: the drop down needs two clicks instead of one in order to be closed
//ToDo: When the drop down is focused, let user close the drop down with Enter

INTERFACE
USES
   System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, System.Types, Vcl.WinXCtrls,
   cvListBox;

TYPE
  TSelectNotifyEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject; SelectedItem: TObject) of object;

  TDropDownSearchBox= class(TSearchBox)
   private
    FOnEndSearch: TSelectNotifyEvent;
    procedure showDropDown;
    procedure endSearch(Sender: TObject);
   protected
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
    procedure Click; override;
    procedure Change; override;
   protected
     lbxSearch: TCubicListBox;
   public
     constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
     procedure  CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
     procedure  SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;                               { SetParent is called during construction AND also during deconstruction with aParent=nil }
     destructor Destroy; override;
     procedure  Populate(Objects: TStringList);
     procedure  SetHostParent(aParent: TWinControl);
     function   SelectedObject: TObject;
   published
     property   OnEndSearch: TSelectNotifyEvent read FOnEndSearch write FOnEndSearch;    { Triggered when the user selected an item from the list }
  end;

procedure Register;



IMPLEMENTATION
USES
   ccCore;





constructor TDropDownSearchBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  AlignWithMargins := True;
  TextHint         := 'Search...';
  OnInvokeSearch   := EndSearch;
  Text             := '';

  lbxSearch := TCubicListBox.Create(Self);
  lbxSearch.Visible := FALSE;
  lbxSearch.OnClick := EndSearch;
  lbxSearch.Parent  := Self;
end;


procedure TDropDownSearchBox.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  lbxSearch.Name      := 'lbxSearch';
  lbxSearch.Width       := Width;
  lbxSearch.Height      := 81;
  lbxSearch.MultiSelect := False;
  lbxSearch.ItemHeight  := 13;
  lbxSearch.Sorted      := TRUE;
  lbxSearch.Visible     := FALSE;

  Text:= '';
end;


procedure TDropDownSearchBox.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
end;


destructor TDropDownSearchBox.Destroy;
begin
  ///FreeAndNil(lbxSearch);  Destroyed by the Parent
  inherited;
end;






procedure TDropDownSearchBox.Change;
begin
  inherited;
  showDropDown;
end;


procedure TDropDownSearchBox.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  showDropDown;
end;


procedure TDropDownSearchBox.showDropDown;
begin
  lbxSearch.Visible:= TRUE;
end;


procedure TDropDownSearchBox.SetHostParent(aParent: TWinControl);
begin
  VAR Pos:= ClientToParent(Point(0, 0), aParent);

  lbxSearch.Parent := aParent;
  lbxSearch.Top    := Pos.Y+ Self.Height+ 2;
  lbxSearch.Left   := Pos.X;
  lbxSearch.Width  := Width;
end;


// Test what happens if the text is not found so the user selects nothing
procedure TDropDownSearchBox.EndSearch(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lbxSearch.Visible:= FALSE; // This must be at the end because of edtSearchReagent.Text:= ActionBl.Reagent.AsText

  if lbxSearch.SelectedObject = NIL then EXIT; // When it happens?

  Self.Text:= lbxSearch.SelectedItem;

  if Assigned(FOnEndSearch) then FOnEndSearch(Self, lbxSearch.SelectedObject);
end;


// Cancel search on Escape
procedure TDropDownSearchBox.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited KeyPress(Key);
  if key = ESC
  then lbxSearch.Visible:= FALSE;;    //ToDo: Allow the user move the cursor down to select from the list.
end;



procedure TDropDownSearchBox.Populate(Objects: TStringList);
begin
  lbxSearch.Clear;
  for VAR i:= 0 to Objects.Count-1 DO
    if (Text = '') OR (PosInsensitive(Text, Objects[i]) > 0)
    then lbxSearch.Items.AddObject(Objects[i], Objects.Objects[i]);
  lbxSearch.SelectFirstItem;

  lbxSearch.SetHeightAuto(300, Parent); //Resize it based on the number of rows in it, but never make it bigger than the 1/2 form
end;


function TDropDownSearchBox.SelectedObject: TObject;
begin
  Result:= lbxSearch.SelectedObject;
end;



procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('LightSaber', [TDropDownSearchBox]);
end;

end.
```

I will post the update on GitHub.