# File combo box in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I want to have file combo box in delphi.
It must behave like this:

1. If i enter C:\ in combo box, it should show all the files & folders in C: Drive
2. If i proceed further i.e., if i enter C:\Pro, then all the files & folders starting with C:\Pro should be shown in combo box.

Simply it should behave like the **File Name Combox Box** that will come while using **save dialog box**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you perhaps mean autocomplete/autosuggest, in which case try the following:

[Google like edit/combo control for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012208/google-like-edit-combo-control-for-delphi/2046649#2046649)

Edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862.aspx

SHAutoComplete will give file functionality - check out [this article](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1852.asp?SK=)