# How to make ComboBox drop-down button invisible in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, combobox

Is there some easy way to customize a ComboBox from Delphi to make the dropdown button with the arrow invisible? I mean without a lot of custom-draw code.. Maybe there is some control specific windows flag to set.

Comment: It is not clear what behavior you are looking for that is specific to the combobox that a tedit does not provide.

Comment: A combobox without a way to drop down the list is an edit control with text validation and hinting. Perhaps that's what you're looking for? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi/5465826#5465826 should help.

Comment: not exactly, im using a DevEx TcxDBLookupComboBox, that has multiple columns in the drowpdown and other functionality.. still I believe the solution will be the same than for the standar delphi TComboBox if it can be done with a windows style flag..

Comment: Set style to `csSimple`, can navigate items with up/down arrows.. Or do you need to drop the dropdown somehow?

Comment: yes I need the dropdown, I just dont want the button..

Comment: If there's no button, how does the user drop down the list (or even know they can)? Also, did you look at the link I provided? It shows a TEdit with a dropped-down list of items.

Comment: @Ken White in TcxDBLookupComboBox the list dropdowns when
1) the user stars typing..
2) the user clicks the control (just like a cxDropDownList TComboBox)
I looked but still I need to use a TcxDBLookupComboBox..

Comment: OK. If you need to use a TcsDBLookupComboBox, why aren't you? I guess I'm missing something here; I've pointed you to an alternative that seems to match your requirements (the list drops down when the user starts typing, and there's no button), but apparently that doesn't work for you (although I'm not sure you looked at it). Can you post a screen shot of what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: In my use-case, I need to toggle LookupComboBox editable and read-only (without that misleading button displayed). It is much simpler to toggle one control, rather than keep two controls (LCB and Edit) synced and switch between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want all the functionality of the cxDBLookupComboBox, just not the button.

Try this in the `FormCreate`:

```
cxDBLookupComboBox1.Properties.Buttons.Clear;
```

You can access other combo box buttons properties via non-published `Buttons` property just like that.

Comment: ``cxDBLookupComboBox1.Properties.Buttons.Items[0].Visible := False;``