# Is it possible to add a history list dropdown to Delphi's TButtonedEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tbuttonededit, tcombobox

I'm using Delphi XE2's TButtonedEdit but I would like to add a dropdown list for the history (like TComboBox). I know that TComboBox is a glorified TEdit, so is there a message I can send to TButtonedEdit to add this functionality please? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this in fact a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi and Ken's answer is what you should be using

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`IAutoComplete2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to accomplish this task.

Check this sample code (adapted for [`TButtonedEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit) and Delphi XE2), based on this answer ([Auto append/complete from text file to an edit box delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi)) from [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white)

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Winapi.ActiveX,  Winapi.ShlObj,
  Vcl.Mask, Vcl.ImgList;


type
  IACList = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{77A130B0-94FD-11D0-A544-00C04FD7d062}']
    function Expand(pszExpand : POLESTR) : HResult; stdcall;
  end;

const
  //options for IACList2
  ACLO_NONE = 0;          // don't enumerate anything
  ACLO_CURRENTDIR = 1;    // enumerate current directory
  ACLO_MYCOMPUTER = 2;    // enumerate MyComputer
  ACLO_DESKTOP = 4;       // enumerate Desktop Folder
  ACLO_FAVORITES = 8;     // enumerate Favorites Folder
  ACLO_FILESYSONLY = 16;  // enumerate only the file system

type
  IACList2 = interface(IACList)
  ['{470141a0-5186-11d2-bbb6-0060977b464c}']
    function SetOptions(dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptions(var pdwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  IAutoComplete = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{00bb2762-6a77-11d0-a535-00c04fd7d062}']
    function Init(hwndEdit: HWND; const punkACL: IUnknown;
      pwszRegKeyPath, pwszQuickComplete: POLESTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function Enable(fEnable: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

const
  //options for IAutoComplete2
  ACO_NONE = 0;
  ACO_AUTOSUGGEST = $1;
  ACO_AUTOAPPEND = $2;
  ACO_SEARCH = $4;
  ACO_FILTERPREFIXES = $8;
  ACO_USETAB = $10;
  ACO_UPDOWNKEYDROPSLIST = $20;
  ACO_RTLREADING = $40;

type
  IAutoComplete2 = interface(IAutoComplete)
  ['{EAC04BC0-3791-11d2-BB95-0060977B464C}']
    function SetOptions(dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptions(out pdwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TEnumString = class(TInterfacedObject, IEnumString)
  private
    type
     TPointerList = array[0..0] of Pointer; //avoid bug of Classes.pas declaration TPointerList = array of Pointer;
    var
    FStrings: TStringList;
    FCurrIndex: integer;
  public
    //IEnumString
    function Next(celt: Longint; out elt;
        pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: Longint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult; stdcall;
    //VCL
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

  TACOption = (acAutoAppend, acAutoSuggest, acUseArrowKey);
  TACOptions = set of TACOption;

  TACSource = (acsList, acsHistory, acsMRU, acsShell);


  TButtonedEdit = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit)
  private

    FACList: TEnumString;
    FAutoComplete: IAutoComplete;
    FACEnabled: boolean;
    FACOptions: TACOptions;
    FACSource: TACSource;
    function GetACStrings: TStringList;
    procedure SetACEnabled(const Value: boolean);
    procedure SetACOptions(const Value: TACOptions);
    procedure SetACSource(const Value: TACSource);
    procedure SetACStrings(const Value: TStringList);
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property ACEnabled: boolean read FACEnabled write SetACEnabled;
    property ACOptions: TACOptions read FACOptions write SetACOptions;
    property ACSource: TACSource read FACSource write SetACSource;
    property ACStrings: TStringList read GetACStrings write SetACStrings;
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ButtonedEdit1: TButtonedEdit;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


uses
  System.Win.ComObj;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonedEdit1.ACEnabled:=True;
  ButtonedEdit1.ACOptions:=[acAutoAppend, acAutoSuggest, acUseArrowKey];
  ButtonedEdit1.ACSource:=acsList;
  ButtonedEdit1.ACStrings.Add('string 1');
  ButtonedEdit1.ACStrings.Add('string 2');
  ButtonedEdit1.ACStrings.Add('string 3');
  ButtonedEdit1.ACStrings.Add('string 4');
end;

{ TEnumString }

function TEnumString.Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
  Pointer(enm) := nil;
end;

constructor TEnumString.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
  FCurrIndex := 0;
end;

destructor TEnumString.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TEnumString.Next(celt: Integer; out elt;
  pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult;
var
  I: Integer;
  wStr: WideString;
begin
  I := 0;
  while (I < celt) and (FCurrIndex < FStrings.Count) do
  begin
    wStr := FStrings[FCurrIndex];
    TPointerList(elt)[I] := CoTaskMemAlloc(2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    StringToWideChar(wStr, TPointerList(elt)[I], 2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    Inc(I);
    Inc(FCurrIndex);
  end;
  if pceltFetched <> nil then
    pceltFetched^ := I;
  if I = celt then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TEnumString.Reset: HResult;
begin
  FCurrIndex := 0;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TEnumString.Skip(celt: Integer): HResult;
begin
  if (FCurrIndex + celt) <= FStrings.Count then
  begin
    Inc(FCurrIndex, celt);
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
  begin
    FCurrIndex := FStrings.Count;
    Result := S_FALSE;
  end;
end;

{ TACEdit }

constructor TButtonedEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FACList := TEnumString.Create;
  FACEnabled := True;
  FACOptions := [acAutoAppend, acAutoSuggest, acUseArrowKey];
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.CreateWnd;
var
  Dummy: IUnknown;
  Strings: IEnumString;
begin
  inherited;
  if HandleAllocated then
  begin
    try
      Dummy := CreateComObject(CLSID_AutoComplete);
      if (Dummy <> nil) and
         (Dummy.QueryInterface(IID_IAutoComplete, FAutoComplete) = S_OK) then
      begin
        case FACSource of
          acsHistory: Strings := CreateComObject(CLSID_ACLHistory) as
            IEnumString;
          acsMRU: Strings := CreateComObject(CLSID_ACLMRU) as
            IEnumString;
          acsShell: Strings := CreateComObject(CLSID_ACListISF) as
            IEnumString;
        else
          Strings := FACList as IEnumString;
        end;
        if S_OK = FAutoComplete.Init(Handle, Strings, nil, nil) then
        begin
          SetACEnabled(FACEnabled);
          SetACOptions(FACOptions);
        end;
      end;
    except
      //CLSID_IAutoComplete is not available
    end;
  end;
end;

destructor TButtonedEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FACList := nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.DestroyWnd;
begin
  if (FAutoComplete <> nil) then
  begin
    FAutoComplete.Enable(False);
    FAutoComplete := nil;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TButtonedEdit.GetACStrings: TStringList;
begin
  Result := FACList.FStrings;
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.SetACEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if (FAutoComplete <> nil) then
  begin
    FAutoComplete.Enable(FACEnabled);
  end;
  FACEnabled := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.SetACOptions(const Value: TACOptions);
const
  Options : array[TACOption] of integer = (ACO_AUTOAPPEND,
                                           ACO_AUTOSUGGEST,
                                           ACO_UPDOWNKEYDROPSLIST);
var
  Option:TACOption;
  Opt: DWORD;
  AC2: IAutoComplete2;
begin
  if (FAutoComplete <> nil) then
  begin
    if S_OK = FAutoComplete.QueryInterface(IID_IAutoComplete2, AC2) then
    begin
      Opt := ACO_NONE;
      for Option := Low(Options) to High(Options) do
      begin
        if (Option in FACOptions) then
          Opt := Opt or DWORD(Options[Option]);
      end;
      AC2.SetOptions(Opt);
    end;
  end;
  FACOptions := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.SetACSource(const Value: TACSource);
begin
  if FACSource <> Value then
  begin
    FACSource := Value;
    RecreateWnd;
  end;
end;

procedure TButtonedEdit.SetACStrings(const Value: TStringList);
begin
  if Value <> FACList.FStrings then
    FACList.FStrings.Assign(Value);
end;

end.
```

And this is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that specific control in XE2 (I'm on 2007 myself), but, assuming the Popup Menu property is one on your control, why not create a popup menu on the form and assign it to that property?  then as you go through items on your control, you can have them get added to the popup menu with a common onclick handler to re-load the prior items as needed.

Comment: Do you envision the popup menu on the edit control? If so, you lose the standard context menu, which is bad. Also, it is hard to discover that feature, and you cannot type while watching the list. Generally, this seems like rather poor GUI design. (But I am not going to downvote! :)