# How to use IAutoComplete together with TStringsAdapter?

Tags: delphi, winapi, autocomplete, com

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012208/google-like-edit-combo-control-for-delphi), it is suggested to use IAutoComplete together with TStringsAdapter to implement auto-complete. The following code tries to follow the suggestion but fails enabling the autocomplete feature without compilation & runtime exception<strike>complaining unmatched/inconsistent interface..</strike>. Could you help to comment about the underlying reason and the work around ?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, AxCtrls, StdVCL, ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  IID_IAutoComplete         = '{00bb2762-6a77-11d0-a535-00c04fd7d062}';
  IID_IAutoComplete2        = '{EAC04BC0-3791-11d2-BB95-0060977B464C}';
  CLSID_AutoComplete: TGUID = '{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}';

type

  IAutoComplete = interface(IUnknown)
    [IID_IAutoComplete]
    function Init(hwndEdit: HWND; punkACL: IUnknown; pwszRegKeyPath: PWideChar;
      pwszQuickComplete: PWideChar): HResult; stdcall;
    function Enable(fEnable: Boolean): HResult; stdcall;
   end;

  IAutoComplete2 = interface(IAutoComplete)
    [IID_IAutoComplete2]
    function SetOptions(dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptions(out dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TStringsAdapterCracker = class(TStringsAdapter);

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAutoComplete: IAutoComplete2;
    FStrings: IUnknown;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  hEditControl: THandle;
begin
  With ComboBox1 do begin
    with Items do begin
      BeginUpdate;
      Clear;
      Add('Alpha');
      Add('Beta');
      Add('Gamma');
      Add('Delta');
      EndUpdate;
    end;
    AutoComplete := False;
    ItemIndex := 0;
  end;

  FAutoComplete := CreateComObject(CLSID_AutoComplete) as IAutoComplete2;
  hEditControl := GetWindow(ComboBox1.Handle, GW_CHILD);
  FStrings := TStringsAdapterCracker(TStringsAdapter.Create(ComboBox1.Items))._NewEnum;
  OleCheck(FAutoComplete.Init(hEditControl, FStrings, nil, nil));
end;

end.
```

Note that related SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615336/is-it-possible-to-add-a-history-list-dropdown-to-delphis-tbuttonededit)) use TEnumString to implement IEnumString manually instead of TStringsAdapter to work with IAutoComplete

Comment: What is the compilation error, which line does it occur?

Comment: The error is run-time and the error message is localized. Furthermore, it happens in the last line of calling Windows API and thus I could not step in to debug.

Comment: `thus I could not step in to debug` - yes, you can. Go into project options and enable "use debug DCUs" checkbox

Comment: blind guess: your `FAutoComplete` var is declared `IAutoComplete2 ` type - the type that does NOT have `.init` method - so you just can NOT call on it, you have to use `IAutoComplete` interface

Comment: So you still won't tell us what the error message is, nor where it is, and you won't debug. Not cool.

Comment: You can find a working example of using `IAutoComplete2` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5465826/62576).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for the confusion. There are no compile or runtime error (exception). The feature is not enabled. Please see edit.

Comment: @Arioch'The Could we step in to debug those `stdcall` IAutoComplete methods ?

Comment: @KenWhite That link is included at the end of the question. It has used TEnumString to implement IEnumString manually instead of TStringsAdapter to work with IAutoComplete, as suggested by the link at the top of the question...

Comment: I didn't say it showed how to use TStringsAdapter. Your code is totally wrong with regard to how it uses IAutoComplete and IAutoComplete2, and I linked to code that shows how to correctly use those interfaces. If I'd thought the linked question was the entire answer, I would have closed this as a duplicate. Implement the correct use of IAutoComplete in your code, and *then* worry about how to convert it to use TStringsAdapter rather than TEnumString.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your suggestion ! Not sure whether it is allowed to change the original (questionable) code in the question drastically....

Comment: You don't have to change anything drastically.  Simply create a `TEnumStrings` implementation that enumerates the `TComboBox.Items` directly, and then replace `FStrings := TStringsAdapterCracker(TStringsAdapter.Create(ComboBox1.Items))._NewEnum;` with `FStrings := TEnumStrings.Create(ComboBox1.Items);` instead.

Comment: `Could we step in to debug those stdcall ` - only in direct x86 assembler. They were not written by you in Delphi - so you do not have source code for those. You can open in Delphi View/Debug Windows/CPU - and step inside machine code, but that hardly would give any helping hand to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could you help to comment about the underlying reason and the work around ?

The reason the code fails is because the `TStringsAdapters` constructor tries to load a StdVCL type library and fails, raising a "library not registered" error:

```
constructor TStringsAdapter.Create(Strings: TStrings);
var
  StdVcl: ITypeLib;
begin
  OleCheck(LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_STDVCL, 4, 0, 0, StdVcl)); // <-- fails!
  inherited Create(StdVcl, IStrings);
  FStrings := Strings;
end;
```

The `TStringsAdapter` object is being constructed in the form's `OnCreate` event, which is triggered after the form's constructor has exited, so the exception does not abort construction or terminate the process, but it does reach a default exception handler that displays an error popup message.  Also, the exception is bypassing the call to `FAutoComplete.Init()`, so no enumerator is created or registered for the ComboBox.

Even though you have added `StdVCL` to your uses clause, that is not enough to get the StdVCL type library registered on the machine that your app is running on.  You would have to distribute and register that type library as part of your app's installation setup.

The workaround is to use a `TEnumString` implementation that simply enumerates the `TStrings` values directly, thus avoiding that requirement.  As well as it has a little bit less runtime overhead then using `TStringsAdapter` (whose `_NewEnum()` method creates a separate `TStringsEnumerator` object to perform the actual enumeration, so you are actually creating 2 objects instead of 1), but at the expense of having to write a bit more code to implement it, eg:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  IID_IAutoComplete         = '{00bb2762-6a77-11d0-a535-00c04fd7d062}';
  IID_IAutoComplete2        = '{EAC04BC0-3791-11d2-BB95-0060977B464C}';
  CLSID_AutoComplete: TGUID = '{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}';

type
  IAutoComplete = interface(IUnknown)
    [IID_IAutoComplete]
    function Init(hwndEdit: HWND; punkACL: IUnknown; pwszRegKeyPath: PWideChar;
      pwszQuickComplete: PWideChar): HResult; stdcall;
    function Enable(fEnable: Boolean): HResult; stdcall;
   end;

  IAutoComplete2 = interface(IAutoComplete)
    [IID_IAutoComplete2]
    function SetOptions(dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptions(out dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAutoComplete: IAutoComplete;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TEnumString }

type
  TEnumString = class(TInterfacedObject, IEnumString)
  private
    FStrings: TStrings;
    FCurrIndex: integer;
  public
    //IEnumString
    function Next(celt: Longint; out elt;
        pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: Longint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult; stdcall;
    //VCL
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings; AIndex: Integer = 0);
  end;

constructor TEnumString.Create(AStrings: TStrings; AIndex: Integer = 0);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStrings := AStrings;
  FCurrIndex := AIndex;
end;

function TEnumString.Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult;
begin
  enm := TEnumString.Create(FStrings, FCurrIndex);
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TEnumString.Next(celt: Integer; out elt;
  pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult;
type
  TPointerList = array[0..0] of Pointer; //avoid bug of Classes.pas declaration TPointerList = array of Pointer;
var
  I: Integer;
  wStr: WideString;
begin
  I := 0;
  while (I < celt) and (FCurrIndex < FStrings.Count) do
  begin
    wStr := FStrings[FCurrIndex];
    TPointerList(elt)[I] := CoTaskMemAlloc(2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    StringToWideChar(wStr, TPointerList(elt)[I], 2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    Inc(I);
    Inc(FCurrIndex);
  end;
  if pceltFetched <> nil then
    pceltFetched^ := I;
  if I = celt then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TEnumString.Reset: HResult;
begin
  FCurrIndex := 0;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TEnumString.Skip(celt: Integer): HResult;
begin
  if (FCurrIndex + celt) <= FStrings.Count then
  begin
    Inc(FCurrIndex, celt);
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
  begin
    FCurrIndex := FStrings.Count;
    Result := S_FALSE;
  end;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  hEditControl: THandle;
  LStrings: IUnknown;
  LAC2: IAutoComplete2;
begin
  with ComboBox1 do
  begin
    with Items do
    begin
      BeginUpdate;
      try
        Clear;
        Add('Alpha');
        Add('Beta');
        Add('Gamma');
        Add('Delta');
      finally
        EndUpdate;
      end;
    end;
    AutoComplete := False;
    ItemIndex := 0;
  end;

  FAutoComplete := CreateComObject(CLSID_AutoComplete) as IAutoComplete;
  hEditControl := GetWindow(ComboBox1.Handle, GW_CHILD); // alternatively, use GetComboBoxInfo() to get the Edit HWND
  LStrings := TEnumString.Create(ComboBox1.Items);
  OleCheck(FAutoComplete.Init(hEditControl, LStrings, nil, nil));
  if Supports(FAutoComplete, IAutoComplete2, LAC2) then
  begin
    // use SetOption as needed...
    OleCheck(LAC2.SetOptions(...));
  end;
end;

end.
```

Also, keep in mind that if the `TComboBox`'s HWND is ever recreated at runtime, you will have to create a new `IAutoComplete` object and call `init()` on it to provide the new HWND.  So you should subclass the `TComboBox` to handle recreation messages, or better would be to use an interceptor class so you can override the `TComboBox.CreateWnd()` method directly, eg:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  IID_IAutoComplete         = '{00bb2762-6a77-11d0-a535-00c04fd7d062}';
  IID_IAutoComplete2        = '{EAC04BC0-3791-11d2-BB95-0060977B464C}';
  CLSID_AutoComplete: TGUID = '{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}';

type
  IAutoComplete = interface(IUnknown)
    [IID_IAutoComplete]
    function Init(hwndEdit: HWND; punkACL: IUnknown; pwszRegKeyPath: PWideChar;
      pwszQuickComplete: PWideChar): HResult; stdcall;
    function Enable(fEnable: Boolean): HResult; stdcall;
   end;

  IAutoComplete2 = interface(IAutoComplete)
    [IID_IAutoComplete2]
    function SetOptions(dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptions(out dwFlag: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TComboBox = class(StdCtrls.TComboBox)
  private
    FAutoComplete: IAutoComplete;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TEnumString }

type
  TEnumString = class(TInterfacedObject, IEnumString)
  private
    FStrings: TStrings;
    FCurrIndex: integer;
  public
    //IEnumString
    function Next(celt: Longint; out elt;
        pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Skip(celt: Longint): HResult; stdcall;
    function Reset: HResult; stdcall;
    function Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult; stdcall;
    //VCL
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings; AIndex: Integer = 0);
  end;

constructor TEnumString.Create(AStrings: TStrings; AIndex: Integer = 0);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStrings := AStrings;
  FCurrIndex := AIndex;
end;

function TEnumString.Clone(out enm: IEnumString): HResult;
begin
  enm := TEnumString.Create(FStrings, FCurrIndex);
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TEnumString.Next(celt: Integer; out elt;
  pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult;
type
  TPointerList = array[0..0] of Pointer; //avoid bug of Classes.pas declaration TPointerList = array of Pointer;
var
  I: Integer;
  wStr: WideString;
begin
  I := 0;
  while (I < celt) and (FCurrIndex < FStrings.Count) do
  begin
    wStr := FStrings[FCurrIndex];
    TPointerList(elt)[I] := CoTaskMemAlloc(2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    StringToWideChar(wStr, TPointerList(elt)[I], 2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
    Inc(I);
    Inc(FCurrIndex);
  end;
  if pceltFetched <> nil then
    pceltFetched^ := I;
  if I = celt then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TEnumString.Reset: HResult;
begin
  FCurrIndex := 0;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TEnumString.Skip(celt: Integer): HResult;
begin
  if (FCurrIndex + celt) <= FStrings.Count then
  begin
    Inc(FCurrIndex, celt);
    Result := S_OK;
  end
  else
  begin
    FCurrIndex := FStrings.Count;
    Result := S_FALSE;
  end;
end;

{ TComboBox }

procedure TComboBox.CreateWnd;
var
  hEditControl: THandle;
  LStrings: IUnknown;
  LAC2: IAutoComplete2;
begin
  inherited;
  FAutoComplete := CreateComObject(CLSID_AutoComplete) as IAutoComplete;
  hEditControl := GetWindow(Handle, GW_CHILD); // alternatively, use GetComboBoxInfo() to get the Edit HWND
  LStrings := TEnumString.Create(Items);
  OleCheck(FAutoComplete.Init(hEditControl, LStrings, nil, nil));
  if Supports(FAutoComplete, IAutoComplete2, LAC2) then
  begin
    // use SetOption as needed...
    OleCheck(LAC2.SetOptions(...));
  end;
end;

procedure TComboBox.DestroyWnd;
begin
  FAutoComplete := nil;
  inherited;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ComboBox1 do
  begin
    with Items do
    begin
      BeginUpdate;
      try
        Clear;
        Add('Alpha');
        Add('Beta');
        Add('Gamma');
        Add('Delta');
      finally
        EndUpdate;
      end;
    end;
    AutoComplete := False;
    ItemIndex := 0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: to make It cleaner perhaps worth checking if FAutoComplete was really created, just like you added OleCheck over other calls

Comment: is it correct that `TEnumString.Skip` might set `FCurrIndex == FStrings.Count == High+1` and still return `S_OK` not `S_FALSE` ?

Comment: @Arioch'The: `CreateComObject()` raises an exception if it cannot create the requested object. `OleCheck()` raises an exception if it is passed a failure HRESULT value. And yes, the behavior of `Skip()` is correct. The return value indicates whether `celt` number of items was skipped or not. Think of what happens when `FStrings.Count` is 1, `FCurrIndex` is 0, and `celt` is 1: `(0 + 1) <= 1` should set `FCurrIndex` to `FStrings.Count` (preventing further skipping/reading) and return `S_OK` because `celt` items are skipped.