# How can I change the textbox (Edit) in a Find dialog to a Combobox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, combobox, autocomplete, customdialog, finddialog

I currently use a standard `TFindDialog` in my Delphi application:

[image: default Find dialog]

How can I change the textbox to a combobox? I'd like to set it up so that the user can easily see and select from the history, like this:

[image: mockup of Find dialog with combobox]

Comment: I always create my own find dialogs/panels. The Win32 one looks a bit dated. It's not hard to make a better one.

Comment: Same here, because I also always want to provide at least "regular expressions" as option and "count all" as button. Using a Combobox instead of an Edit for the text to provide an MRU list is a secondary feature I add (including the possibility to delete single entries thru the `Delete` key again when the list is displayed and one item selected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I currently use a standard FindDialog in my Delphi application.
>
> How can I change the text box to a combo box?

You can't, at least not with `TFindDialog`, as it does not allow the use of a custom dialog template (the underlying `FindText()` API does, though).

However, there is another workaround for your situation...

In the `TFindDialog.OnShow` event, use [`FindWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) to manually find the `HWND` of the Edit field in the dialog, and then use the Shell's [`IAutoComplete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nn-shldisp-iautocomplete) interface to enable a drop-down list on that `HWND`.  You can write a class that implements the [`IEnumString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ienumstring) interface to provide the entries that you want to appear in that drop-down list (for instance, by wrapping a `TStringList` that you store your entries in).

See MSDN documentation for more details:

[Using Autocomplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776884(v=vs.85))

[How to Enable Autocomplete Manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-enable-autocomplete-manually)

Also see:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2046649/65863) to [Google like edit/combo control for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012208/)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465826/65863) to [Auto append/complete from text file to an edit box delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324637/65863) to [How to use IAutoComplete together with TStringsAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317985/)