# Access violation assigning autocomplete strings to

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, controls

I am modifying the edit control with autocomplete from here: 
[Auto append/complete from text file to an edit box delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi)

I want to load autocomplete strings from DB. I declared new properties on autocomplete control descendant:

```
FACDataSource : TDataSource;
FACFieldName : string;
```

I call this to load autocomplete strings:

```
procedure TAutoCompleteEdit.ReadSuggestions;
begin
  FAutoCompleteSourceList.Clear;

  if (not Assigned(FACDataSource)) or (not Assigned(FACDataSource.DataSet))       or (not ACEnabled) then
      exit;

    with FACDataSource.DataSet do
    begin
       if Active and (RecordCount > 0) and (FACFieldName <> '') then
       begin
         First;
         while not EOF do
         begin
                       FAutoCompleteSourceList.Add(FACDataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(FACFieldName).AsString);
    Next;
  end;
  if FAutoCompleteSourceList.Count > 0 then
    ACStrings := FAutoCompleteSourceList;
end;
```

end;
end;

However, I get AccessViolation when assigning `FAutoCompleteSourceList` to `ACStrings`. The setter for `ACStrings` is:

```
procedure TAutoCompleteEdit.SetACStrings(const Value: TStringList);
begin
    if Value <> FACList.FStrings then
      FACList.FStrings.Assign(Value);
end;
```

I get AccessViolation in the line: `FACList.FStrings.Assign(Value);` (READ of address XXXYYY). `Value` is defined and not garbage at that point (e.g. in I can view the string list in the debugger). 'FStrings' is an empty stringlist.

It works fine when the control is dropped on the form. But doesn't if I place it within a custom inplace editor shown when user enters a DBGridEH cell.

The inplace editor is like this:

```
    unit UInplaceAutoCompleteEditor;

    interface
    uses UDBAutoComplete, UMyInplaceEditor, classes, windows, Controls, Buttons,     DB;

    type TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor = class(TMyInplaceEditor)
      private
       FEditor : TAutoCompleteEdit;
    FButton : TSpeedButton;
    FShowButton : boolean;
    procedure SetShowButton(value : boolean);
    public
        constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
        procedure SetFocus; override;
        destructor Destroy; override;
     protected
    procedure EditorKeyDown(Sender : TObject; var Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState);
    function GetACDataSource : TDataSource;
    procedure SetACDataSource(value : TDataSource);
    function GetACFieldName : string;
    procedure SetACFieldName(value : string);
    procedure SetACEnabled(value : boolean);
    function GetACEnabled : boolean;
  published
    property Editor : TAutoCompleteEdit read FEditor;
    property ACDataSource : TDataSource read GetACDataSource write SetACDataSource;
    property ACFieldName : string read GetACFieldName write SetACFieldName;
    property ACEnabled : boolean read GetACEnabled write SetACEnabled;
    property Button : TSpeedButton read FButton;
    property ShowButton : boolean read FShowButton write SetShowButton;
end;

  procedure Register;

implementation

  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('nikolaev', [ TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor ]);
  end;

{ TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor }



constructor TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FEditor := TAutoCompleteEdit.Create(self);
  FEditor.Parent := self;
  FEditor.Align := alClient;
  FEditor.Visible := true;
  FEditor.WantTabs := true;
  FEditor.OnKeyDown := EditorKeyDown;

  FButton := TSpeedButton.Create(self);
  FButton.Parent := self;
  FButton.Align := alRight;

  self.FOwnHeight := -1;
  self.FOwnWidth := -1;

  SetShowButton(false);
end;

destructor TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.Destroy;
begin
  Feditor.Destroy;
  FButton.Destroy;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.EditorKeyDown(Sender: TObject;
  var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key in [ VK_Return, VK_Tab ] then
  begin
    self.Value := FEditor.Text;
    Key := 0;
    ConfirmValue;
  end;

  if Key = VK_Escape then
  begin
    Key := 0;
    CancelValue;
  end;

  inherited;
end;



function TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.GetACDataSource: TDataSource;
begin
  Result := FEditor.ACDataSource;
end;

function TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.GetACEnabled: boolean;
begin
  Result := FEditor.ACEnabled;
end;

function TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.GetACFieldName: string;
begin
  Result := FEditor.ACFieldName
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.SetACDataSource(value: TDataSource);
begin
  FEditor.ACDataSource := value;
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.SetACEnabled(value: boolean);
begin
  FEditor.ACEnabled := value;
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.SetACFieldName(value: string);
begin
  FEditor.acfieldname := value;
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.SetFocus;
begin
  inherited;
  FEditor.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TInplaceAutoCompleteEditor.SetShowButton(value: boolean);
begin
  if value <> FShowButton then
  begin
    FShowButton := value;
    FButton.Visible := value;
  end;
end;

end.
```

This inplace editor inherits from an abstract class like this:

```
unit UMyInplaceEditor;

interface
uses Windows, classes, types, dbGridEh, ExtCtrls, Controls;

type TMyInplaceEditor = class (TWinControl)

  private
    FOnValueConfirmed : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnCanceled : TNotifyEvent;
    FWantTabs : boolean;
    procedure AdjustPosition;
  protected
    FOwnHeight, FOwnWidth : integer;
    FValue : Variant;
    function GetIsEditing : boolean;
    procedure SetIsEditing(value : boolean); virtual;
    procedure ConfirmValue;
    procedure CancelValue;
    procedure SetValue(val : Variant); virtual;
  public

    property OnValueConfirmed : TNotifyEvent read FOnValueConfirmed write FOnValueConfirmed;
    property OnCanceled : TNotifyEvent read FOnCanceled write FOnCanceled;
    property Value : Variant read FValue write SetValue;


    property IsEditing : boolean read GetIsEditing write SetIsEditing;
    procedure SetPosition(parentControl : TWinControl; rect : TRect); virtual;

    function ColumnEditable(column : TColumnEH) : boolean; virtual;

    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    property WantTabs : boolean read FWantTabs write FWantTabs;
end;
  procedure Register;

implementation

  procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents('nikolaev', [TMyInplaceEditor]);
  end;

constructor TMyInplaceEditor.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  self.AutoSize := false;
  self.Visible := false;
  self.FOwnHeight := -1;
  self.FOwnWidth := -1;
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.AdjustPosition;
var xOffset, yOffset : integer;
begin
  xoffset := self.Left + self.Width - self.Parent.Width;
  if xOffset > 0 then
    self.Left := self.Left - xOffset;

  yOffset := self.Top + self.Height - self.Parent.height;
  if yOffset > 0 then
    self.Top := self.Top - yOffset;

end;

function TMyInplaceEditor.GetIsEditing : boolean;
begin
  Result := self.Visible;
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.SetIsEditing(value: Boolean);
begin
  self.Visible := value;
  self.BringToFront;
  {if Visible then
    self.SetFocus;}
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.SetPosition(parentControl : TWinControl; rect: TRect);
begin
  self.Parent := parentControl;
  self.Top := rect.Top;//parentControl.Top;
  self.Left := rect.Left;//parentControl.left;
  if self.FOwnWidth = -1 then
    self.Width := rect.Right - rect.Left
  else
    self.Width := self.FOwnWidth;

    if self.FOwnHeight = -1 then
    self.Height := rect.Bottom - rect.Top
  else
    self.Height := self.FOwnHeight;
  AdjustPosition;
end;

function TMyInplaceEditor.ColumnEditable(column : TColumnEH) : boolean;
begin
  Result := true;
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.ConfirmValue;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnValueConfirmed) then
    FOnValueConfirmed(self);
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.CancelValue;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnCanceled) then
    FOnCanceled(self);
end;

procedure TMyInplaceEditor.SetValue(val : Variant);
begin
  FValue := val;
end;

end.
```

The InplaceEditor is used in a descendant from `DBGridEH`. I override ShowEditor and HideEditor to show / hide my editor in certain cases.

Again, the autocomplete control only throws exception when embedded in the inplaceeditor control.

What causes access violation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the code you are using mis-handles interface reference counting. Here are the relevant extracts:

```
type
  TEnumString = class(TInterfacedObject, IEnumString)
  ....
```

Note that this class is derived from `TInterfacedObject` and so it manages its lifetime using reference counting.

Then the code goes on like this:

```
type
  TAutoCompleteEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    FACList: TEnumString;
  ....
```

So we are going to hold a reference to the object rather than the interface. That looks dubious already.

Then we do this:

```
constructor TAutoCompleteEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FACList := TEnumString.Create;
  ....
end;

destructor TAutoCompleteEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FACList := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

There's nothing here to keep the object alive. At other points in the code we take a reference to the `IEnumString` interface. But then as soon as that reference is released, the object thinks that there are no references left. And so it is deleted. Then, later on, the code refers to `FACList` which now points at an object that has been destroyed.

---

A simple way to fix this would be to make sure that the `TAutoCompleteEdit` control always holds a reference to the interface:

```
type
  TAutoCompleteEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    FACList: TEnumString;
    FEnumString: IEnumString;
....
constructor TAutoCompleteEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FACList := TEnumString.Create;
  FEnumString := FACList;
  ....
end;
```

And with this change you can then remove the destructor for `TAutoCompleteEdit` since the object behind `FEnumString` will get destroyed by the reference counting mechanism.

---

Another way to fix this would be to change `TEnumString` to disable automatic reference counting. That would look like this:

```
type
  TEnumString = class(TObject, IInterface, IEnumString)
  private
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
    ....
  end;

function TEnumString.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TEnumString._AddRef: Integer; 
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function TEnumString._Release: Integer; 
begin
  Result := -1;
end;
```

And then you'd need the `TAutoCompleteEdit` destructor to look like this:

```
destructor TAutoCompleteEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FACList.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

---

And a final option would be to avoid holding a `TEnumString` at all and instead only hold an `IEnumString` reference. Let the reference counting manage lifetime as in the first solution. But then you'd need to implement another interface that allowed the `TAutoCompleteEdit` to obtain the `TStrings` object.

Comment: @KenWhite Your linked answer is otherwise very good. It would perhaps be best if you could fix the code there.

Comment: @David: Done, and thanks. (I opted for your first suggestion, as it seemed to me the cleanest.)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks. I can see merits to all three options which I guess is why I failed to nail my colours to the mast!