# Delphi, edit Auto-Complete access violation in tenumstring at TPointerlist()

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, delphi-10.1-berlin

In [this autocomplete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465590/auto-append-complete-from-text-file-to-an-edit-box-delphi/5465826#) by @KenWhite, the Next function has an access violation when `TPointerList()[]` is called ( by the windows autocomplete interface.)

D10.1u2, Win10.64

```
function TEnumString.Next(celt: Integer; out elt;
   pceltFetched: PLongint): HResult;
var
 I: Integer;
wStr: WideString;
begin
 I := 0;
 while (I < celt) and (FCurrIndex < FStrings.Count) do
   begin
     wStr := FStrings[FCurrIndex];
     TPointerList(elt)[1] := PWideChar('abcd');  //access violation
     TPointerList(elt)[1] := CoTaskMemAlloc(8);  //access violation
     TPointerList(elt)[I] := CoTaskMemAlloc(2 * (Length(wStr) + 1)); //access violation
     StringToWideChar(wStr, TPointerList(elt)[I], 2 * (Length(wStr) + 1));
     Inc(I);
     Inc(FCurrIndex);
  end;
 if pceltFetched <> nil then
  pceltFetched^ := I;
 if I = celt then
 Result := S_OK
else
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;
```

Comment: What is your question. And where is the rest of your code? [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: So, what is your question, and where is the [mcve]?

Comment: I don't see a question here either. I just see a problem, a function, and a link to another question. I also don't see what's so hostile about David's comment.

Comment: @Henry I read the whole blog post you linked but I still don't know what to do with a bug report of an answer posted on the site.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The link was a full working? example. One you yourself claim to have used elsewhere on this very site.

Comment: Nope, don't think I've ever compiled that code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(elt)` needs to be `(@elt)`, and `[1]` needs to be `[I]`:

```
TPointerList(@elt)[I]
```

Then the code will not AV anymore.

Also, the output strings must be allocated with either `SysAllocString...()` or `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, as the caller is going to use the COM memory manager to free them.  You can use the RTL's `ComObj.StringToLPOLESTR()` function to handle that for you, which makes a COM-allocated wide string copy of a Delphi `String`:

```
TPointerList(@elt)[I] := StringToLPOLESTR(FStrings[FCurrIndex]);
```

Alternatively, you can simply take ownership of the `WideString`'s data pointer instead of making yet another copy in memory after `WideString` has already made one:

```
wStr := FStrings[FCurrIndex];
TPointerList(@elt)[I] := Pointer(wStr);
Pointer(wStr) := nil;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, `TPointerList(@elt)[I] := StringToLPOLESTR(FStrings[FCurrIndex]);` fixed it. Strange that the original code appears to have been used by multiple people successfully, including our esteemed DH

Comment: Note that the definition of `TPointerList` was changed, IIRC in Delphi XE2. Before XE2 it was `TPointerList = array[0..MaxListSize-1] of Pointer;`. In XE2, it became `TPointerList = array of Pointer;`. That could explain why the original example code, as it was, does not work anymore in newer versions: there is one extra level of indirection. It is also a little problematic to cast to what has become a dynamic array here, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis true, which is why I don't like using `TPointerList` at all. I would probably just cast `elt` to `PPointer` and increment+dereference it on each loop iteration

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions (IIRC XE2 and above), you can do what Remy says, but IMO you should not.

In versions before XE2 (or whatever version it was), the definition of `TPointerList` was:

```
type
  ...
  TPointerList = array[0..MaxListSize] of Pointer;
```

In the newer versions, it is:

```
type
  TPointerList = array of Pointer;
```

In other words, instead of a *static* array type (a value type), it has become a *dynamic* array type (a reference type) now. Casting the address of an untyped out parameter to such an array *can* turn out to be tricky.

The difference in definition explains why in newer versions, the code does not work properly: there is one extra level of indirection.

Now if you add the following declaration to the *uAutoComplete.pas* file:

```
type
  TPointerList = array[0..65535] of Pointer; // assuming 65536 (2^16) entries are enough
```

then the rest of the file can remain what it used to be. Then:

```
TPointerList(elt)[I] := ...
```

works and does not require you to use a slightly tricky, indirect, cast to a Delphi dynamic array on something that is actually not. Note that this will also work in older versions.

Comment: Nice catch. Indeed this answers the question *"The link was a full working? example.*" which is the only thing that resembles a question posted by the OP, although it's *asked* in the comments and although not exactly sure what it means.