# How can I filter the contents of a combo box based on what's been typed?

Tags: delphi, autocomplete, combobox

We have a combo box with more than 100 items.

We want to filter out the items as we enter characters in combo box. For example if we entered 'ac' and click on the drop down option then we want it to display items starting with 'ac' only.

How can I do this?

Comment: Who are "we"? There is the difference between individuals and corporations when do consulting for them.

Comment: I fail to see how that distinction affects the answer to the question, @Down. A combo box is a combo box.

Comment: @Downvoter: probably the difference between 'the police have' and 'the police has'.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you'd be happier using the autocompletion features built in to the OS. I gave [an outline of how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012208/google-like-edit-combo-control-for-delphi) here previously. Create an `IAutoComplete` object, hook it up to your combo box's list and edit control, and the OS will display a drop-down list of potential matches automatically as the user types. You won't need to adjust the combo box's list yourself.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Rob's answer about using the OnChange event, here is an example of how to do what he suggests.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FComboStrings := TStringList.Create;
  FComboStrings.Add('Altair');
  FComboStrings.Add('Alhambra');
  FComboStrings.Add('Sinclair');
  FComboStrings.Add('Sirius');
  FComboStrings.Add('Bernard');
  FComboStrings.Sorted := True;
  ComboBox1.AutoComplete := False;
  ComboBox1.Items.Text := FComboStrings.Text;
  ComboBox1.Sorted := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FComboStrings);
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Filter: string;
  i: Integer;
  idx: Integer;
begin
  // Dropping down the list puts the text of the first item in the edit, this restores it
  Filter := ComboBox1.Text;
  ComboBox1.DroppedDown := True;
  ComboBox1.Text := Filter;
  ComboBox1.SelStart := Length(Filter);

  for i := 0 to FComboStrings.Count - 1 do
    if SameText(LeftStr(FComboStrings[i], Length(ComboBox1.Text)), ComboBox1.Text) then
    begin
      if ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf(FComboStrings[i]) < 0 then
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(FComboStrings[i]);
    end
    else
    begin
      idx := ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf(FComboStrings[i]);
      if idx >= 0 then
        ComboBox1.Items.Delete(idx);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Aargh, you're too fast for me! +1

Comment: @NGLN: :-)) (It happens to me all the time as well)

Answer (score 2):

My brief contribution working with objects in the combobox:

```
procedure FilterComboBox(Combo: TComboBox; DefaultItems: TStrings);

  function Origin: TStrings;
  begin
    if Combo.Tag = 0 then
    begin
      Combo.Sorted := True;
      Result := TStrings.Create;
      Result := Combo.Items;
      Combo.Tag := Integer(Result);
    end
    else
      Result := TStrings(Combo.Tag);
  end;

var
  Filter: TStrings;
  I: Integer;
  iSelIni: Integer;
begin
  if(Combo.Text <> EmptyStr) then
  begin
    iSelIni:= Length(Combo.Text);
    Filter := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for I := 0 to Origin.Count - 1 do
        if AnsiContainsText(Origin[I], Combo.Text) then
          Filter.AddObject(Origin[I], TObject(Origin.Objects[I]));

        Combo.Items.Assign(Filter);
        Combo.DroppedDown:= True;
        Combo.SelStart := iSelIni;
        Combo.SelLength := Length(Combo.Text);
    finally
      Filter.Free;
    end;
  end
  else
    Combo.Items.Assign(DefaultItems);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the combo box's `OnChange` event. Keep a master list of all items separate from the UI control, and whenever the combo box's edit control changes, adjust the combo box's list accordingly. Remove items that don't match the current text, or re-add items from the master list that you removed previously.

Answer (score 1):

As Rob already answered, you could filter on the OnChange event, see the following code example. It works for multiple ComboBoxes.

```
{uses}
  Contnrs, StrUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ComboBox2: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FComboLists: TList;
    procedure FilterComboBox(Combo: TComboBox);
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TComboBox then
    FilterComboBox(TComboBox(Sender));
end;

procedure TForm1.FilterComboBox(Combo: TComboBox);

  function Origin: TStrings;
  begin
    if Combo.Tag = 0 then
    begin
      Combo.Sorted := True;
      Result := TStringList.Create;
      Result.Assign(Combo.Items);
      FComboLists.Add(Result);
      Combo.Tag := Integer(Result);
    end
    else
      Result := TStrings(Combo.Tag);
  end;

var
  Filter: TStrings;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Filter := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to Origin.Count - 1 do
      if AnsiStartsText(Combo.Text, Origin[I]) then
        Filter.Add(Origin[I]);
    Combo.Items.Assign(Filter);
    Combo.SelStart := Length(Combo.Text);
  finally
    Filter.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FComboLists := TObjectList.Create(True);
  // For Each ComboBox, set AutoComplete at design time to false:
  ComboBox1.AutoComplete := False;
  ComboBox2.AutoComplete := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FComboLists.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Hmm, a bit superfluous now. :(