# What do I need to implement in order to use predictive typing for TEdit

Tags: delphi

Hello I want for my clients to be able to use windows predictive typing in my software, but I cannot figure out why does it work only for TComboBox and not TEdit, TMemo, TRichEdit. Nor can I find anything on the matter on msdn or elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know what "predictive typing" is. Do you mean "autocompletion"? If so, the WWW is full of examples. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012208/google-like-edit-combo-control-for-delphi

Comment: There are solutions for both a combobox and an edit in the link I provided as a duplicate.

Comment: I mean the built in windows predictive typing. You can turn that on by going to settings, typing, 'show text suggestions as I type pm the software keyboard' and 'show tex suggestions as I type'. This functionality works only with TComboBox out of the box and not TEdit, TMemo... I can't figure out do I need to handle any messages or what exactly to do so it starts working.